# Registering Shopify Webhooks - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, shopify, webhooks

I am creating a shopify app and currently, i want to register webhooks in my app so that if a customer is created, a notification/sms to sent to the admin.
According to my research, it can be registered through the shop settings but in this case, i want to register it via the app.  But there are not enough resources to get this done.. Below is what i have but when i create a customer, my sms is not sent to the admin..

What could i be missing out now ?

**VerifyWebhook**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
    $hmac = request()->header('x-shopify-hmac-sha256') ?: '';
    $shop = request()->header('x-shopify-shop-domain');
    $data = request()->getContent();

    // From https://help.shopify.com/api/getting-started/webhooks#verify-webhook
    $hmacLocal = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $data, env('SHOPIFY_SECRET'), true));
    if (!hash_equals($hmac, $hmacLocal) || empty($shop)) {
        // Issue with HMAC or missing shop header
        abort(401, 'Invalid webhook signature');
    }


    return $next($request);   
    }
```

**Route**

```
 Route::post('webhook/shopify/customer-created', function(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
    // Handle customer created and sms or notification
})->middleware('webhook');
```

Comment: In laravel by default csrftoken for post request is checked you will have to exclude that url from $except array in App\Http\Middleware > VerifyCsrfToken file.

Comment: @somsgod, that is not the issue but i can't really tell if my webhook is properly done

Comment: Then you dont have to do it like above. During the app installation once you get the code for installing the app , before getting access token. You can register the webhook in enter this 'topic' => ' customers/create' with the post url which will be your return server url like eg: webhook/shopify/customer-created. Then once that is done on user creation activity this webhook will trigger which in turn will call this url webhook/shopify/customer-created.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to verify webhook instead of creating one. Please go through below process

Create a webhook using simple request:

```
POST /admin/webhooks.json
{
  "webhook": {
    "topic": "customers/create",
    "address": "https://whatever.hostname.com/",
    "format": "json"
  }
}
```

ofcourse you will have to pass shopify auth token in headers.

If you want to use a package to ease the process you can use: https://github.com/oseintow/laravel-shopify

your ***routes.php/web.php***

```
Route::get('/register-webhook', 'WebhooksController@registerCustomerWebhook')->name('customer');

Route::get('/webhooks/customer-created', 'WebhooksController@customerCreated')->name('customerCreated');
```

and then import and use it -->

```
use Oseintow\Shopify\Facades\Shopify;
.
.
// create a webhook
public function registerCustomerWebhook(...){
Shopify::setShopUrl($shopUrl)->setAccessToken($accessToken)->post("admin/webhooks.json", ['webhook' => 
    ['topic' => 'customers/create',
    'address' => 'https://whatever.hostname.com/path',
    'format' => 'json'
    ]
]);
```

.
}

Verifying webhook:

```
public function customerCreated(...) {
    if (Shopify::verifyWebHook($data, $hmacHeader)) {
        // do your stuffs here in background
        return response('Hello World', 200)
        ->header('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    } else {
    return response('UnAuthorized', 401)
        ->header('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    }
.
.
}
```

Note:

1. Your endpoint must have proper ssl certificates installed
2. You need to respond to an webhook as quickly as possible. Its better to do your tasks in background.

Let me know if there is any confusion.

Comment: I have installed the package into my composer.json. I want now create the webhook but into which file do i have to add the webhook in laravel ?

Comment: @Switz sorry for the late response, check the updated answer and let me know if any clarification is required